# How can I remove the mongodb.cluster message?

Tags: java, mongodb, jar, jongo

I am developing a `JSF` application with `MongoDB` connection with `Jongo` but the console is showing  the next message and I would like remove its:

```
Grave:   9 [http-listener-1(4)] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
Grave:   1293 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5848a8f264e75c14f0363dac', description='null'}-localhost:27017] INFO org.mongodb.driver.connection - Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:124}] to localhost:27017
Grave:   1300 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5848a8f264e75c14f0363dac', description='null'}-localhost:27017] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 2, 9]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=4, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=3243563}
Grave:   8059 [http-listener-1(4)] INFO org.mongodb.driver.connection - Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:125}] to localhost:27017
```

My `Java` code is:

```
this.coleccion = (new Jongo(new MongoClient("localhost", 27017).getDB("mydb"))).getCollection("mycollection");
```

I am using the next tecnologies (`JARs`):

- mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar
- bson4jackson-2.7.0.jar
- jackson-annotations-2.7.3.jar
- jackson-core-2.7.3.jar
- jackson-databind-2.7.3.jar
- jongo-1.3.0.jar

Thank you